# Canon 5D Mark III + Multiple shots in single shutter release?

Tags: bracketing, canon-5d-mark-iii, shutter-release

I have gotten hold of Canon 5D Mark III and trying to use AEB.

I would like to know if camera can take multiple shots with just one single press of shutter release instead of pressing multiple times or keep pressing?

IF so please let me know where I can find that setting.

Comment: I have not tried this but maybe it is possible using an intervalometer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to page 170 of [the manual](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/42005.pdf) the only way to have it automatically do it on its own is to remote/timer setting with 2 second or 10 second timer.  This will result in all three shots taken with one press.  Otherwise, you have to hold down in continuous modes or press three times in single shot modes.

Comment: Using a tripod with a wired remote and holding the button down in continuous drive mode is about the closest you will get to what I think you are looking for. If you are trying to do it handheld, just hold down the shutter button until the required number of frames have been taken.

Answer (score 2):

[Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm/) has an advanced bracketing feature that allows you to set 2-9 frames, at 0-5EV intervals. The bracketed set is taken with a single shutter button press. There's also a mode where it can automatically evaluate the scene to set the number of shots needed to cover the dynamic range.

There's also the dual-ISO mode which will let you basically do HDR in a single exposure by using two different ISO settings on alternate lines of the image which can be software interpolated to fuse the two different exposures.

However, the 5DMkIII is not one of the cameras supported in the latest stable release of ML, so you'll have to make a judgment call on whether you want to risk a 5DMkIII to a nightly build.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the 2 second delay on, but trigger it with an IR remote instead of the shutter or wired remote, it will take the bracket immediately.

Answer (score 0):

"I would like to know if camera can take multiple shots...
IF so please let me know where I can find that setting."

Just above the top LCD screen there are three buttons for 1) WB 2) AF and 3) ISO.
Turn camera on and press the middle button "AF-DRIVE" button. While holding down the AF button, turn the "Main Dial" top wheel just behind the shutter release and select desired auto focus.  Still pressing the "AF" button, turn the back "Quick Control Dial" to the desired shutter release.  As mentioned previously, see page 112 for further info.

Hope that helps - worked for me.